# Proving the minimality of an element order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Assume that I have a finite group G of order n with a generator g, and also assume that I want to prove that $\frac{n}{gcd(n,m)} $ is the order of an element $x = g^m \in G$.

First , I showed that $x^\frac{n}{gcd(n,m)} = e$

let $d = gcd(n,m)$ then $d | n$ and $d|m$ and so $dt=n,ds=m$ for some integers $t,s$ now $t = \frac{n}{gcd(n,m)} = \frac{n}{d}$ then $x^\frac{n}{d} = (g^m)^\frac{n}{d} = g^\frac{mn}{d} = (g^n)^\frac{m}{d} = e$
 then now I want to show that $t$ is minimal , meaning that it's the least positive integer such that $x^t = e$. Here is my attempt

Suppose that $x^k = e$ for some positive integer k, now by the division algorithim, we have $k = tq + r$ where $ 0 \leq r < t$ , so $x^k = x^{tq+r} = x^{tq}x^r = (x^t)^qx^r = e^qx^r=ex^r=x^r$ , now I want to show that $r = 0$ to conclude that $k=tq$ and hence $ k \geq t$ and so $t$ is the order.

But how do I show that $r$ is zero , any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Since $g$ has order $n$, $x^k=g^{km}=e\iff n\mid km$. Let $n=n'\gcd(m,n)$ and $m=m'\gcd(m,n)$, so $\gcd(m',n')=1$. Then, $n\mid km\iff n'\gcd(m,n)\mid km'\gcd(m,n)\iff n'\mid km'\iff n'\mid k$. So the smallest $k$, which is the order of $x$, is $n'=\frac{n}{\gcd(m,n)}$.